# how can i decrement an int column of a SQLite table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a table in my data base that has three columns: Screen, Icon, and Rank: and i am trying to find the cleanest way to achieve the following..

i want to find all rows WHERE Screen = "myScreen" and Rank >5 // then make rank one less than current value..  I am doing this in Java via a SQLite Manager class in the  following function:

```
public void DeleteScreenIcon (int id, String screenName, int rank){
        int screenID = getScreenID(screenName);
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(isLookUp, colScreenID + "=" + screenID + " and " +colIconID+ "="+id, null);
        // HERE IS WHERE I NOW WANT TO DO THAT..
        db.execSQL("update "+ isLookUp +" set "+colRank+ "=" +colRank+ " -1 "+" where " + colScreenID +  "='"  +screenName + "' and " + colRank +">" +rank);
        db.close();
    }
```

sorry, im not that versed in SQL any help is appreciated

Comment: In SQL, you can simply do `Rank=Rank-1` in an update statement.

Comment: I have a similar problem:-

`ContentValues dataToInsert = new ContentValues();                          
        
dataToInsert.put(MARKER_ID, MARKER_ID+"-1");

String where = IMAGE_ID_F+" = " +imageId+ " AND "+MARKER_ID+" > "+markerId+";";
        
int resultUpdate = db.update(TABLE_DEFECTS, dataToInsert, where, null);`

Comment: The above doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This update should do the trick:

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET Rank = Rank - 1
WHERE Screen = "myScreen"
AND Rank > 5;
```

Comment: thank you was not sure you could use set like that.. AWESOME!

Comment: i added a line of code above to my method to reflect your response and wondering if i am formatting this correct in java?